# Clean sheet: How to build your own boilerplate with Github, Atom, Jekyll & Bootstrap for a 1 scroll web page

Tags: github, twitter-bootstrap-3, jekyll, atom-editor, gemfile

### Introduction:

So far I have not found any dummie guide on building a simple boilerplate. I am done using templates from other people. I have basic experience in building projects with Github, Atom, Markdown, Liquid, Jekyll & Bootstrap. So just need a hand with a couple of things.

Link to repo: https://github.com/bomengeduld/debadkamer

Other project I build succesfully, thanks to a template: https://github.com/werkbaar/werkbaar:

**I like to stay as close as possible to this kind of rootdirectory, since I am used to work with that.**

### Target:

**Im trying to establish an easy step by step "workflow" without to much Jargon, so also other starting designers can benefit from this. Can you help me with this?**

### **What I have done so far**:

1) Created a "NEW" repo on Github, with just a README file. 
2) Cloned to GH desktop by clicking "Open in desktop" 
3) Opened the project in Atom 
4) Build the basic rootdirectory 
5) Added gemfile:

a) Made a gemfile in directory  
 b) Opened rootdirectory in command  
 c) Installed bundle with following command: bundle install

[image]

### Problem:

**From this point on I get stuck and not sure which step to do first. In my assumption that bootstrap is a gem. I Added the gemfile. I did because at one installation tutorial they described it: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass**

d) Installed bundle again with following command: gem install bundler 

[image]

### **RootDirectoy:**

```
    ├── _includes
    |   └── head.html
    |   └── nav.html
    |   └── header.html
    |   └── footer.html
    ├── _layouts
    |   └──default.html
    ├── assets
    |   ├── css
    |   ├── fonts
    |   ├── img
    |   └── js
    ├── .git
    ├── _config.yml
    ├── gemfile
    ├── gemfile.lock
    ├── index.html
    └── README.md
```

For some reason the Assets folder is not added to my repo on github. probably because it does not contain any files yet.

### **Question:**

**How to Add Bootstrap 3 to my project & install the full gemlist needed?**

**Any other recommendations to make this a nice Clean Sheet?**

**Disclaimer:** F*or those that like to assist:
Please explain as simple and practical as possible.*

Comment: Hello, I don't know the whole stack you're using but, from what I understand, this might help you https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-bootstrap-sass

Comment: Hi Dan Lowe, thx for your tip! 

It is still very unclear to me to how the bootstrap files are added to rootdirectory... do i just have to download them and add them to the css folder in rootdirectory?

Comment: Hi, It's Mebius actually. Dan Lowe is the guy who edited your post (tags and some characters where removed). To adress your issue: the stack you use implies you'll be using SASS which is some kind of super language for CSS. So, if you want to use SASS you will want to use the gem I linked in my paste comment. Once you've added it to your gemfile, you can install it by running "bundle install" in a command prompt (see http://bundler.io/). To use the gem, refer to the readme  part of https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-bootstrap-sass. If you want to use bootstrap in a classic CSS manner,

Comment: simply add `<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` on top of your layout\default.html (in the <HEAD> section)

Comment: My apologies Mebius,

Apparently, the most friendly way I was looking for was to install bootstrap locally. Which is obvious, becausee with jekyll we build the website locally.



I downloaded the DIST file, and copied the css, fonts, js folders to my rootdirectory.  I then copied the basic template to head.

Is this enough to get started?


I understand now, that you explained me the CDN method. 

Is there a big difference?

Disclaimer: I use bootstrap 3

Comment: Well, I personally tend to use a CDN and put my customisation locally, but what I explained to you works with local files too. If you want to use the CSS version of bootstrap, put it in assets/css and then add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" >` in the HEAD section of your layout/default.html

Comment: Btw the bonus of using a CDN is that you don't have to host a big file for no reason and you can easily keep it up to date. The drowback is that you can't customize the file itself and the file might change without you being noticed.

Comment: Ow, you make a great point.. This makes the website much less slumpy

Now I understand the difference.